# Flask url_for stop accepting double-digit user IDs. BUG?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am relatively new to Flask and I could not figure out what is the problem with my function nor I could find that someone had had the same problem. It is even difficult to explain.

**Template url_for link:**

```
<a href="{{ url_for('view_post', pc=post.product_category_by.product_cat_name, post_id=post.id, ui=post.author_id) }}">
```

**Flask view function:** (Flask SQLAlchemy. PostgreSQL)

```
@app.route('/viewref/<pc>/<int:post_id><int:ui>')
    def view_post(pc, post_id, ui):
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter_by(id=post_id).first()
    db.session.commit()
    gc.collect()
    return render_template('view_post.html', post=post)
```

**Example:**

Lets take a post with ID **26** and two users (or authors of post) with IDs **9** and **10**. When I pass a user with ID **9**, I get redirected to the correct view with the end url: `/viewref/productCat/269` (**26** is post id and **9** is user id). Great, it works and I see a post!

**The problem:**

But when a user with ID **10** or higher (12, 299 etc.) get passed in the `url_for`, the query of `view_post` function pulls `None` from the database, subsequently my view_post.html template throws an Error

```
(UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'product_category_by')
```

What is the connection?

The key of the `view_post` function is only to fetch a post by a given `post_id`. Why does it get `None` in the cases where user ID > 9, if my function takes only post_id for the query and other variables are used for the url construction only?

P.S. It all works fine if I exclude `ui` from the `url_for` and `view_post` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're expecting the URL router to tell where `post_id` ends and `ui` starts. You should use an actual separator:

```
@app.route('/viewref/<pc>/<int:post_id>/<int:ui>')
```

Comment: @igsm - sheer luck? :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your URL scheme. What if the user id is 12 and the post_id is 34? In your URL it would be concatenated to 1234. How can we tell this apart from post_id: 1, user_id: 234 versus post_id: 123, user_id: 4?